# How to read appsettings.json with array of values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have the following appSettings.json file:

```
  "SundrySettings": {

    "CookieName": "Cookie",

    "AccessGroup": "Software Development",

    "Terminals" :  {
      "Raucherplatz" : "tablet1.local",
      "Service" :      "tablet2.local",  
      "Technik" :      "tablet3.local",  
      "Technik" :      "tablet4.local",  
      "Container" :    "tablet5.local"
    }
  }
}
```

That I would like to load into the following structure:

```
    public class Terminal
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Description;
    }

    public class SundryOptions
    {
        public string CookieName { get; set; } = "dummy";
        public string HRAccessGroup { get; set; } = "dummy";
        public List<Terminal> Terminals;
    }
```

that I would try to load using the following commands:

```
ServiceProvider sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
SundryOptions sundryOptions = sp.GetService<IOptions<SundryOptions>>().Value;
```

The problem I have is that using Property Initialisers never sets the Terminals List correctly. I do need a list (and not a Dictionary) as the enties could be double i.e. Technik in my example.

I am assuming that I have some error in the Class -> I would be happy for any pointers.

Comment: Don't use a List. What you posted there is a *dictionary*, typically represented as an object. It's not a list. You *can't* parse it as a list

Comment: I did try 

sundryOptions.Terminals = Configuration.GetSection("SundrySettings:Terminals").Get<List<Terminal>>();

in ConfigureServices but that did not work unfortunately

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did try a dictionary as well but still get null for the value of Terminals

Comment: Using which class? The `Terminal` class you posted doesn't match the `Terminal` in the json file. `Technik` is a *setting*, not some name in a name/value pair. The path to that setting is `SundrySettings::Terminals::Service` and its value is `tablet2.local`. I suspect you're trying to use the Configuration subsystem like a database?

Comment: That means `Technik` will throw too, because it's not unique. That's how the Configuration system works - each setting has a specific path and a value. Those settings can be mapped to strongly-typed objects. If the objects match the settings, this is trivial. If not, you'll have to write code to map one to the other

Comment: You may want to look at this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846296/how-to-load-appsetting-json-section-into-dictionary-in-net-core).

Comment: @UrsusSchneider You marked the copied answer as correct answer. Great! Thank you. When the both answer become similar then you should check the edit history of the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement processing of configuration as following somewhere approporiate like this:

```
var cookieName = 
Configuration.GetSection("SundrySettings:CookieName").Value;
var accessGroup = Configuration.GetSection("SundrySettings:AccessGroup").Value;

var terminals = new List<Terminal>()

var terminalSections = this.Configuration.GetSection("Terminals").GetChildren();
foreach (var item in terminalSections)
{
    terminals.Add(new Terminal 
    {
           // perform type mapping here 
    });
}

SundryOptions sundryOption = new SundryOptions()
{
        CookieName = cookieName,
        HRAccessGroup = accessGroup,
        Terminals = terminalList
};
```

Of course there could be shorter version, but you can start from here.

Comment: Brother fully copied my answer :) Okay! no problem. :)

Comment: Nope mate. I answered first you just added the boilerplate to that... :) then I filled the boilerplate in. But if you have hard feelings just vote it down.

Comment: No no! I don't feel envy to anybody so that I shall down vote. It's ok. Best of luck. By the way there is edit history  your first answer was wrong too. Ok. Keep going.

Answer (score 9):

Do as follows:

```
var cookieName = Configuration.GetSection("SundrySettings:CookieName").Value;
var accessGroup = Configuration.GetSection("SundrySettings:AccessGroup").Value;
var terminals = Configuration.GetSection("SundrySettings:Terminals").GetChildren();

List<Terminal>  terminalList = new List<Terminal>();

foreach (var keyValuePair in terminals)
{
     Terminal termial = new Terminal()
     {
          Name = keyValuePair.Key,
          Description = keyValuePair.Value
     };

     terminalList.Add(termial);
}

SundryOptions sundryOption = new SundryOptions()
{
            CookieName = cookieName,
            HRAccessGroup = accessGroup,
            Terminals = terminalList
};
```

I have checked with the exact configuration you provided and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

If Terminals is a list, in your appSettings, it should be an array, not an object.

```
  "Terminals" :  [
  "Raucherplatz" : "tablet1.local",
  "Service" :      "tablet2.local",  
  "Technik" :      "tablet3.local",  
  "Technik" :      "tablet4.local",  
  "Container" :    "tablet5.local"
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the info -> your example is missing curly brackets within the [ ] i.e. like this: [ { ... } ]