# Injecting app settings via DI based on generic type in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to be cheeky and create a base service for my MongoDB client. Inside my DI container I've injected database connection settings from the `application.json` (as per [Microsoft’s MongoDB tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)).

What I can't figure out is the best way to access one of these setting properties based on a generic type passed into the constructor for the base service.

For example, the MongoDB collection name for Type `Player` is named is *Players*. One idea I had was to do `typeof(T)` instead of putting the key/value in the settings, but that cements the collection name to the type name.

Here is the database settings object being injected:

```cs
    public class GameDatabaseSettings : IGameDatabaseSettings
    {
        public string PlayersCollectionName { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
        public string LobbiesCollectionName { get; set; }
    }
```

The application json:

```js
"GameDatabaseSettings": {
    "PlayersCollectionName": "Players",
    "LobbiesCollectionName": "Lobbies",
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb+srv://bugbeeb:*******@csharptest-yzm6y.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "DatabaseName": "DiceGameDB"
  },
```

And here is how the base service operates:

```cs
    public interface IGameItem
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class BaseService<T> where T:IGameItem
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<T> _collection;
        public BaseService(IGameDatabaseSettings settings)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
            var db = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);
            _collection = db.GetCollection<T>(settings.CollectionName); //<-- How to make this T specific??
        }
        public virtual async Task<T> GetAsync(string id)
        {
            var result = await _collection.FindAsync(item => item.Id == id);
            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        public virtual async Task DeleteAsync(string id)
        {
            await _collection.FindOneAndDeleteAsync(item => item.Id == id);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with `typeof(T)`. The only step you were missing is that you can [bind a list of key/value pairs in your `appSettings.json` to a `Dictionary<string, string>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846296/how-to-load-appsetting-json-section-into-dictionary-in-net-core) in your `GameDatabaseSettings`.

That will let you look up configuration values based on a string name, thus allowing you to configure the mappings between any generic `Type` and an associated MongoDB collection name via your `appSettings.json`.

So given the following `appSettings.json`:

```
"GameDatabaseSettings": {
    "CollectionNames": {
      "Players": "Players",
      "Lobbies": "Lobbies"
    },
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb+srv://bugbeeb:*******@csharptest-yzm6y.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "DatabaseName": "DiceGameDB"
  }
}
```

You can bind to a settings object like:

```cs
public class GameDatabaseSettings : IGameDatabaseSettings
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> CollectionNames { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
}
```

And now, within your service, you should be able to do something like:

```cs
_collection = db.GetCollection<T>(settings.CollectionNames[typeof(T).Name]);
```

Of course, you shouldn’t *assume* that the correct mapping will be configured, so you’ll likely want to write more defensive code, similar to:

```cs
_collection = db.GetCollection<T>(
  settings.CollectionNames.TryGetValue(
    typeof(T).Name,
    out var collectionName
  )? 
    collectionName :
    throw new ConfigurationError(
      $"The ‘{typeof(T).Name}’ mapping is not configured as part of {nameof(GameDatabaseSettings)}."
    )
);
```

Comment: That is clever, I didn't know you could map a dictionary

Comment: @Bugbeeb: Yeah! The configuration system is surprisingly flexible. The only real limitation here is that the keys must be strings currently—which is obviously fine for your needs. That said, you can even use complex objects as your values should you ever need to introduce additional dimensions to your data (e.g., multiple piece of metadata per type, beyond just the collection name). Good luck with your project.